# Как вызвать произвольный участок памяти в качестве указателя на функцию

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер

Подскажите, можно ли как-то передать управление программы на C/C++ в произвольный доступный участок памяти?

Сделал тестовый пример (mingw, Windows), но не работает, программа аварийно завершается при вызове **pw3(5)**.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void work1(int value){
    cout << "work1 " <<value <<endl;
}

void work2(int value){
    cout << "work2 " <<value <<endl;
}

void (*pw1)(int) = work1;
void (*pw2)(int) = work2;
unsigned char data[100]={};
unsigned char *funcData = (unsigned char *)pw1;

int main() {
    cout << "start test programm" << endl;

    work1(1);
    work2(2);

    pw1(3);
    pw2(4);

    cout <<(void*)pw1 << endl;
    cout <<(void*)pw2 << endl;


    void (*pw3)(int) = (void (*)(int))data;

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        data[i] = funcData[i];

    }
    pw3(5);

    cout <<"end work"<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В произвольный, пусть даже и доступный, - нет! Вы создаёте `data` в DATASEG, а ОС не выпустит за пределы CODESEG. Можно "поиграть" с функциями WinAPI, но на чистом C/C++ этого сделать нельзя.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/275861/ возможно вам чем-то поможет, обратите внимания на специальные прагмы.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Execute shellcode by casting to function pointer in Visual C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9593287/4279)

Comment: На микроконтролерах с архитектурой фон Неймана , подобный код может сработать.

Comment: Возможно, эта статья вам поможет. https://tproger.ru/translations/main-is-usually-a-function-so-then-when-is-it-not/

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593287/execute-shellcode-by-casting-to-function-pointer-in-visual-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно или нельзя это сделать зависит не только от "правильности" конвертации указателей, но и от свойств подлежащей платформы. Ни одна современная [интерактивная] ОС не позволит вам просто так передавать управление в область данных. Это один из столпов обеспечения безопасности системы. Защита подобного рода (Data Execution Prevention) реализована как на уровне ОС, так и на уровне процессора.

Возможно, ваша ОС предоставляет средства для отключения этой защиты. Без отключения этой защиты вам необходимо ОС-зависимыми средствами пометить ваши данные, как выполняемый код, и только после этого передавать туда управление. Но для доступа к соответствующему API ваша программа должна обладать необходимыми (весьма высокими) привилегиями.

Отдельно стоит заметить, что вам никто не обещал, что код функции располагается в памяти неким компактным непрерывным образом. Т.е. ваше верование в то, что ваш цикл `for` копирует в массив `funcData` именно код функции, ничем не обосновано.

Также нет гарантии, что код функции является позиционно-независимым. Если вы специально не обеспечили генерации позиционно-независимого кода, то может получится, что даже в случае успешного копирования кода функции в массив `funcData`, это код на новом месте все равно не будет вести себя так, как вы ожидаете.

Comment: изменил подопытный код, перезаписал данные функции work2, все равно программа падает при попытке вызова

Comment: @Alex: А что вы хотели? Вы делаете сложную низкоуровневую хрень, и рассчитываете, что сможете отделаться простым копированием памяти? Оттрассируйте выполнение кода до и после копирования, найдите разницу в значениях регистров. Ничего сложного в этом нету, просто скучная и кропотливая работа.

Comment: @Alex, AnT (на мой взгляд  несколько завуалировано) написал же вам, что код, который скопирован в `data[]` не может исполняться, т.к. **эта память не доступна для исполнения**. Можете поинтересовться в гугле по ключевым словам `виртуальная память  права доступа защита памяти`